# cannot resolve symbol PreviewCallback

Tags: java, android, camera

I created a class in java for capturing pictures from a phone camera and I get the following error cannot resolve the PreviewCallback symbol.
[image]

Comment: What API level are you targeting in your app-level `build.gradle`? The old Camera API [was deprecated in API 21](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback)

Comment: the API level is 21

Comment: I'd say that's the reason then. Either convert your project to use the `Camera2` API, or lower the API level.

Comment: which is API level to use camera1 API ?

Comment: API 20 or below

Comment: I seted API level to 19 and don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using incorrect `Camera` class.

First remove this line

```
import android.graphics.Camera;
```

Then add this line

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
```